# For some reason I am unable to validate data

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am trying to validate my data but for some reason I am getting this error 
**" Trying to get property 'title' of non-object"**

**Here's My Controller:-**

```
public function store(Request $request)

{
  $data = request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
      ]);


     Post::create([
            'title'=>$data->title,
            'body'=>$data->body,
            'created_by'=>$request->created_by,
            'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
            'filled_by'=>Auth::user()->uuid,

          ]);


  return redirect('/home');


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request()->validate([]);` will return Array with validated data. You are using `$data->title` but `$data` is NOT an Object but Array.

Instead use

```
'title' => $data['title'],
```

Comment: So you can mark this answer as correct (question solved) :)

Comment: @cojnicki hey  can you help me out with another question, ist about notification